# Cannot build a C++ project with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project which uses CMake, and I want to try using Eclipse CDT with mingw (this project already compiles and run with MSVC, code::blocks, etc.)

With Eclipse CDT, I choose a target, and right click to build the target, but I get the following message :

> 22:59:13 **** Build of project OgreProcedural-RelWithDebInfo@ogreprocedural_eclipse ****
>   "e:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -C E:/Prog/Builds/ogreprocedural_eclipse OgreProcedural 
>   Cannot run program "e:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe": Invalid directory.
>   Error: Program "e:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" not found in PATH
>   PATH=[E:\Prog\ImageMagick;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.26.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;e:\prog\libs\qt\bin;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;e:\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin;e:\python;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin]

... but the mingw\bin directory is in the path, and mingw32-make is inside it.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
Finally, I was able to build projects, but among the multitude of build targets generated by CMake, some build fine and some others don't.

Comment: Did you try changing `%PATH%` to match the case of the actual folder (i.e. change `e:\mingw\bin;` to `e:\MinGW\bin;`?

Comment: Changed PATH : didn't work. Changed PATH and re-ran CMake : compiles ok! Thanks! Anyway, paths are case insensitive in windows, so eclipse should behave the excepected way. I think I'm gonna file a bug...

Comment: Spoke too early... It compiled only once, recompiling with the same conditions doesn't work... grrr

Comment: When you go into command prompt and it lands you at `C:`, if you type `cd E:\something` then nothing happens. You have to switch to `E:` to go into that working dir on another drive. I wonder whether Eclipse is struggling with switching working directories to the `E:` drive. What happens when you load Eclipse with E: as the initial working dir?

Comment: No, I retried with Eclipse, Eclipse's workspace, Mingw, and the project all on the same drive, and I still get the issue. I'm now thinking it may be a CMake bug, which I'll report. Anyway, I have a workaround, now, at least...

Comment: Could you tell something on how you did it? I am struggling with a similar problem